# how to notmapped or ignore propery of inherited class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I have a brand poco class as below.

```
 [Table("Brand")]
public partial class Brand
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]


    public int BrandId { get; set; }


    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

}

I need to extended with baseEntity as shown below. I created a partial class in order to prevent re-creating the class shouldnt override it.

```
public partial class Brand : BaseEntity 
{


}
```

BaseEntity class has some static methods and a Id property as shown below.
When I debug my application it complains that Id is not a valid column.

```
   public abstract partial class BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

It is clear that I need to ignore or sign as NotMapped but I dont want to change BaseEntity and I dont want to change my DbContext class (re-creating can override)

I can create a partial class of Dbcontext as shown below and use ignore. But It wont allow me to use OnModelCreating 2 times.

How can I achieve this task without making any change in the BaseEntity Class?

```
public partial class MyDBContext : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>().Ignore(t => t.Id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how it makes sense in your case to inherit an ID and then want to make a new ID and ignore the other? Sounds like a design issue. If you don't want a property, don't inherit it.

Comment: I am creating a plugin for nopcommerce shop and this baseentity class is by default there and my customer designed the table as above with BrandId, if he was designed as Id, i wouldnt have this problem. I would suggest to change the DB but before I want to know if there is anyway workaround this.

Comment: @EricHotinger Lets assume, it is not Id, something else if it is confusing. Purpose is to ignore the attribute which is defined in the abstract class.